# node.js on heroku: Error: Cannot find module 'csv'

Tags: node.js, csv, heroku

I'm using a common node package 'csv' to do CSV parsing.  It works great on my local mac, but not on heroku.  In the "heroku log", I get ***Cannot find module 'csv'***.

Yes, I have it in my package json file:

```
{
    "name":"rimes",
    "version":"0.0.1",
    "dependencies":{
    "sys":"",
    "url":"",
    "http":"",
    "querystring":"",
    "oauth":"0.9.10",
    "fs":"",
    "csv":"0.3.0",
    "request":"",
    "node-cache":"",
    "underscore":""
    }
}
```

and I require it in my app.js

```
var sys = require('sys'),
http = require('http'),
url = require('url'),
qs = require('querystring'),
OAuth= require('oauth').OAuth,
fs = require('fs'),
csv = require('csv'),
myreq = require('request'),
NodeCache = require('node-cache'),
us = require('underscore');
```

What can I do to fix this on heroku?

Thank you,
~Todd

Comment: is it installed locally or globally ? To see global packages do npm list -g for local npm list

Comment: I don't understand your question.  I'm trying to run my app on heroku.

Comment: how did you install package csv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So when you require packages on node, you also need to install them in your node_modules folder. They must be in the node_modules folder as well as "required" in your code. They can only be declared in your "package.json."

If you go into your project directory (the file where package.json is located) and run:

`npm install`

it should install your missing dependencies into your 'node_modules' folder.

Then if you re-deploy your app to heroku it should work.